# How to render a form with a user's data?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users

How do I create a django form to display a user's sell objects with a radio box next to each obejct for deletion? 
I'm trying to create something similar to the django admin where users are listed with radio boxes for quick deletion.

[image: django forms]

From the request.user I'm trying to get the Sell's associated objects from a user and return a list 
of sells in order to delete the selected. So far my profile form looks like this:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    sells = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.Select(
            sell=Sell.object.filter(user=self.request.uwer)
        )
    )
```

In the views.py I plan to delete selected sell objects like so:

```
for sell in form.sells:
    sell = Sell.objects.get(id=sell)
    sell.delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few things wrong here. The most significant is that you can't set the choices in the form definition, as you don't have access to `request.user` there.

I don't think you want a model form, anyway. Those are for creating and editing model instances, whereas you simply want to list existing instances with a checkbox. So you just want a normal form with a field that represents those instances, ie a ModelMultipleChoiceField.

So, the form looks like this:

```
class DeleteSellForm(forms.Form):
    sells = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Sell.objects.none(),
                                           widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(DeleteSellForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sells'].queryset=Sell.objects.filter(user=user)
```

You'll notice that the queryset defaults to none, but is set to the correct user's objects in the `__init__` method, where we can pass in the user.

So the view looks like this:

```
def delete_sells(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = DeleteSellsForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.cleaned_data['sells'].delete()
    else:
        form = DeleteSellsForm(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

`ModelMultipleChoiceField` cleans to a QuerySet, so you should be able to call `delete()` on it directly.

Comment: Woops, I actually meant to use form.Form. Model.forms require the `class Meta:...`. Thanks! This worked!

Comment: One more question, why do we need to pop the user? as in `user = kwargs.pop('user', None)`